# Creating a line in Java Swing that is the length of an int in an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop

I'm trying to draw a forloop of lines all spaced apart by 10 and I want the lines to be the length of the number of the int in the array. When I try to set their size as numbers[i] it gives me an array index out of bounds error the array is of size 50 and is filled with random numbers from 20-100.

```
private void drawPass(Graphics g) {
    int space = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
        g.drawLine(space, 1000, numbers[i], numbers[i]);
        space += 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If not, can you provide some feedback?

Answer (score 2):

If your array is of length 50, then the last index you can access is 49 since the arrays are indexed starting at 0. In your current situation you are trying to access index 50 (which is what `numbers.length` is) which doesn't exist.

Change

```
i <= numbers.length;
```

to

```
i < numbers.length;
```

The change was from `<=` to just `<`. Now, instead of looping from 0-50, it goes from 0-49. To help visualize this

```
[5, 8, 3, 4, 9]   // Random array of ints   (  length   = 5)
 0  1  2  3  4    // Index of each position (last index = 4)
```